Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function twig_split_filter(), 2 passed
I'm working on a project php/twig and i got problem in my template while calling the split function of Twig
the Error i get is
enter image description here
i tried to wrok on the parametrs but still get the same problem
here is my admin.twig

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function twig_split_filter(), 2 passed in /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(358) : eval()'d code on line 417 and at least 3 expected in /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php:743 Stack trace: #0 /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(358) : eval()'d code(417): twig_split_filter(Object(Twig\Environment), '10000') #1 /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(173): __TwigTemplate_ea6172f395bc9ef2f3fa79c411f9070f78998bd5979a4921466cd07b6a7b63e0->block_content(Array, Array) #2 /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(358) : eval()'d code(74): Twig\Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array) #3 /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCyc in /home/software/apache/htdocs/sandbox/PHP8/MitarbeiterLifeCycle/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php on line 743

{% set safeties = ["allg", "labor", "s1"] %}
{% set suArrRequire = ("1" ~ data.pflichtSU)|split('') %}
{% for safety in safeties %}
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary radio-inline {% if suArrRequire[loop.index0] == 1 %}active{% endif %}" for="yes{{ loop.index0 }}">
                <input type="radio" name="data[suRequire][{{ safety }}]" id="yes{{ loop.index0 }}" value="1" autocomplete="off" {% if suArrRequire[loop.index0] == 1 %}checked{% endif %}><span class="tr" key="yes"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary radio-inline {% if suArrRequire[loop.index0] == 0 %}active{% endif %}" for="no{{ loop.index0 }}">
                <input type="radio" name="data[suRequire][{{ safety }}]" id="no{{ loop.index0 }}" value="0" autocomplete="off" {% if suArrRequire[loop.index0] == 0 %}checked{% endif %}><span class="tr" key="no"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>


Please post the error message as text, not a screenshot. And keep the original formatting, with each step in the traceback on its own line.

I've removed the core code as this has no relevance in your question. Anyhow, your error makes no sense, unless you've altered the CoreTwigExtensions, the first parameters is auto-injected, the second is the value passed from the template and the third is an optional argument. You will need to provide more details

i have edited the post with the error as text
